# Using MOV instruction

Tags: assembly, emu8086

How to write in assembly language these instructions.
First one:

```
org 100h
mov ax ,0b00h
mov ds ,ax
```

You have to put in the memory address 0becah the value from al.
Second one:

```
org 100h
mov ax ,0900h
mov ds ,ax
```

You have to put in bl the value from the memory address 092a0h
For the first one I tried :
    mov [0cah],al
and for the second one:
   mov bl, [a0h]
Are they correct, or have I misunderstood the questions?

EDIT:
I get [0cah] from:

```
0b00h**10h +x= 0becah  
x=00eca
```

So, since al is 8 bit I take only cah.

And I get [a0h] form:

```
0900h*10h+x=092a0h  
x=002a0h
```

And same with the previous one I take only the a0h part

Comment: Is this NASM? You clearly are not using correct syntax.

Comment: Use a comma between operands, like `mov ds, ax`.  Normally with `org 100h`, you're making a `.com` executable with a tiny memory model, so you don't need to set segment regs; they're already all equal.

Comment: Edited. The point is if the questions are written good in assembly language.

Comment: Putting in the memory address 0becah the value from al. Translating this to code.

Comment: Can you explain how you get the address 0becah from 0b00:00ca and how you get the address 092a0h from 0900:00a0?

Comment: @prl Okay, I explained it in the edit section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the memory address is not dependent on the size of the value to be stored. You don't truncate the upper 8 bits of the address when storing an 8 bit value.

The answers should be:

```
    mov [0ecah], al

    mov bl, [02a0h]
```

Comment: Thank you, and one more thing, is the second one solved like that or should it be: mov bl, a0h

Comment: `mov bl, 0a0h` would load the value 0a0h into bl. To read from memory, you need the brackets. (The syntax for what is a memory reference and what is an immediate value depends on the assembler you are using.)